# How to access abstract class connection string in controller c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, connection-string, abstract-class

Here my connection string in Abstract class, how can I access my connection string?

```
public abstract class Connection
{
    public SqlConnection sqlConn = null;

    public SqlConnection GetConnection
    {
        get { return sqlConn;}
        set { value = sqlConn; }
    }

    public Connection()
    {
        string cons = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTXDb"].ConnectionString;
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(cons);
   }
}
```

HomController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
  //Connection db = new Connection();  /// cannot create instance of an abstract class
   public HomeController:Connection()
   {
    //Here How can i get my connection 
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this an ASP thing? your classes have nothing in common. your abstract class needs at least a field/Property... to acces the connection. Maybe ApiController has a field Connection? ```Getconnection:Connection()``` is wrong (say VS 2015) there is no such notation. So you can access Members of the Parant class simply by this.Fieldname/Propertyname or leave the "this" out. e.g. ``` ```this.sqlConn``` or simply ```sqlConn``` if inheriting from ```Connection```

Comment: do you need that function in your constructor? why did you have an abstract and then a constructor?

Comment: @Nazerane my connection is not create an instace thats my main intension

Comment: well constructors are mainly meant to create a new instance. If you use the constructor it will create a new instance.

Comment: If you want to use the connection, the descendants of the abstract class, at some point, needs to know it. you can Create a Field, Property, or/and pass it as an Constructor argument. Maybe you want to extract an IConnection interface, which is used by the abstract class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not instantiate an abstract class, instead you should implement this class then use inherited class in your controller.

First create a new class

```
public class SqlServerConnection : Connection
{

}
```

Then in your controller

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    SqlServerConnection conn = new SqlServerConnection();
    internal void Getconnection
    {
        SqlConnection connection = conn.GetConnection();
    }
}
```

By the way, if abstract class is for multiple connection types (such as Sql server, Oracle etc) I recommend you to reconsider your code, you can easily find best practices for this by searching.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for multiple inheritance, which C# doesn't have. Instead you can chain the types. You should also give them more meaningful names.

So instead of `Connection`, name it `SqlConnectionApiController` or something, so it looks like this:

```
public abstract class SqlConnectionApiController : ApiController
{
    // ...
}
```

Then your `HomeController` can inherit from that type:

```
public class HomeController : SqlConnectionApiController 
{
    public HomeController()
    {
        var connection = base.GetConnection();
    }
}
```

So the inheritance tree looks like this:

```
HomeController : SqlConnectionApiController : ApiController
```

I would also consider not using the SqlConnection directly, but using a higher-level construct such as an ORM, for example through Entity Framework.

Comment: Just for my knowledge: Better approach is to use interface for the connection string.. suggestion?

Comment: @Div why would an interface help here?

Comment: In that case, no need to create `SqlConnectionApiController` we can directly inject dependency to the home controller!

Comment: But it's no dependency, it's inherited. For it to be injected there would have to be a constructor parameter, and there has to be a non-abstract class to be injected. I don't see a reason for this class to be abstract in that scenario anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First inherit Abstract Class and then You can use the connection string...
When you have to access anything from abstract class then you need to inherit that abstract class and then you can use it.

Comment: shaik where can i inheriate my connection

Comment: in controller class

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with not having your code in your constructor, 
Make your connection string a static variable:

```
static SqlConnection sqlConn = null;

public static SqlConnection GetConnection 
    => sqlConn ?? (sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTXDb"].ConnectionString));
```

Or a more readable code:

```
static SqlConnection sqlConn = null;

public static SqlConnection GetConnection {
get {
    if (sqlConn == null)
    {
        string cons = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTXDb"].ConnectionString;
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(cons)
    }
    return sqlConn ;
}
}
```